# Check for duplicates in Google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

hoping someone can help here.

I am simply looking to identify duplicate names in one column and update a drop-down in another. The only caveat to this would be to allow one to pass as unique with the rest being duplicated. I have posted a screenshot as a demo of what I'm looking to achieve.

So in here you will see Bob appearing 3 times, the first should be yes to unique with the other 2 being no.

| Name | Unique |
| --- | --- |
| Bob | Yes |
| Charles | Yes |
| Audrey | Yes |
| Bob | No |
| Bob | No |

[image: Example]

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-sheets-formula/info) for official documentation, free resources and more details.

Answer (score 3):

use:

```
=INDEX(IF(A2:A="";;IF(COUNTIFS(A2:A; A2:A; ROW(A2:A); "<="&ROW(A2:A))=1; "yes"; "no")))
```

[image]

Comment: Can you explain this solution?

Comment: @Fabian sure. first we COUNTIFS each name in A2:A with A2:A but in a such way that if name in A2:A repeats the count will increase. this will result in array of 1,1,1,2,3 (based on the image example). next we pair it with boolean logic adding =1 to it and we wrap it into IF to output yes each time the name appears first time otherwise it will be no. to make sure it will stop at row 6 we wrap it again into IF and output nothing if row in A column is empty.